# PHP if or statement not working

Tags: php, if-statement

We are trying to use the below piece of code

```
if (($_GET['1'] != "1") || ($_GET['1'] != "2")) {
```

When we try this no matter what value the variable has it will evaluate as true even when data is entered that is false. When we use

```
if (($_GET['1'] == "1") || ($_GET['1'] == "2")) {
```

and put in data that will make it return false it works correctly. We have reversed the way that the if statement goes just so we can get this working but i would like to know why this doesnt work, if it is something im doing wrong or a limitation within php with the or and the not equal operators

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your first test is saying this:

> If `$_GET['1']` is anything other than `"1"` OR `$_GET['1']` is anything other than `"2"`

The expression will always pass: If it equals `1` it will pass the `!= '2'` test on the second half of your if statement. If it equals `2` it will pass the `!= '1'` test on the first half, and never make it to the second half of the test.

The second test simply says:

> If `$_GET['1']` equals `"1"` OR `$_GET['1']` equals `"2"` then the expression should pass

You probably want this expression, which will pass only if neither parameter holds the correct value:

```
if(($_GET['1'] != '1') && ($_GET['1'] != '2'))
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression below will always evaluate to TRUE, because either x is not 1 or x is not 2.  There is no way that x can equal both 1 and 2 at the same time!

```
($x != 1) || ($x != 2)
```

The opposite of

```
($x == 1) || ($x == 2)
```

is

```
($x != 1) && ($x != 2)
```

Note that you have to change the || to a &&.

Comment: ohh , tankx that sparked something in my head..:)..Had same kind of problem

Answer (score 1):

Try:

if (($_GET['1'] != "1") && ($_GET['2'] != "2")) {

If you use != in both statements, then you need to use && instead of || to make sure both statements get evaluated.

Essentially, using || means that the first statement gets evaluated and if it is false, then PHP will ignore the second statement because you are using OR.  But if you use &&, then PHP will be sure to evaluate both != statements.

Answer (score 0):

if your code is:

```
if (($_GET['1'] != "1") || ($_GET['2'] != "2")) {
```

any value or even null value can enter this condition. you can change || to && meaning any string which is not equal to "1" and "2" can enter you condition

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the intention of the statement, or what input you started with (or how you revised it), I can't say for certain what the issue is.

That said, the first statement will only evaluate to `FALSE` if `$_GET['1']` is equal to 1 and `$_GET['2']` is equal to 2.

The second statement will only evaluate to `FALSE` if `$_GET['1']` is not equal to 1 and `$_GET['2']` is not equal to 2.

I'm guessing what you wanted on your first statement was

```
if (($_GET['1'] != "1") && ($_GET['2'] != "2")) {
```

which evaluates to `FALSE` unless `$_GET['1']` is equal to 1 and `$_GET['2']` is equal to 2.