# Not condition in PHP not working

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Why is this not working:

```
if ($name != "alex" or "james"){
        echo '<script> alert("error");</script>';
        echo '<script> window.location.replace("demo.php");</script>';
}
```

but this is?

```
if ($name != "yo"){
    echo '<script> alert("error");</script>';
    echo '<script> window.location.replace("demo.php");</script>';
}
```

I have also tried using `||` instead of or and `$name != "alex" or $name != "james"` but that also doesn't work. Does anybody know why?

Comment: How many times will it take before people will stop asking the same questions and find the myriad of times they've already been answered: `if ($name != "alex" or $name != "james"){`

Comment: @MarkBaker it's one of those [Dunning-Kruger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) related things where people who can't solve logic puzzles also can't master searching for how to do it.

Comment: I think it is unfair to down vote because it was an easy answer... And anyway it wasn't more people got it wrong than write... Dont get me wrong I love snobs!!

Comment: It's not the difficulty, it's the fact that SO is overflowing with near-copies of this question which you could have searched and used as a template for your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781434/php-if-or-statement-not-working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745452/php-conditional-statement-not-working-properly

Comment: Both of them are not that similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for an *and*:

```
if ($name != "alex" or "james"){
```

Changed to:

```
if ($name != "alex" && $name != "james"){
```

The problem with yours is it checks if name does not equal Alex **or** if 'james' is equivalent to true, which it is since it is defined.

Comment: @James I am using `!=` aka does not equal.

Comment: @Anonymous sorry, I completely read the code wrong even when I re-typed it out again.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example won't work, because you need to compare `$name` again.

```
if ($name != "alex" && $name != "james"){
    echo '<script> alert("error");</script>';
    echo '<script> window.location.replace("demo.php");</script>';
}
```

Comment: This would always be equivalent to true since name can never equal two different things.

Comment: No... It's saying if `$name` is equal to this, **or** if `$name` is equal to this, then do something, if it's not, don't do it.

Comment: You are saying if the name is **not** equal to alex or it is **not** equal to james, then it is true, but it can not equal both at once.

Comment: Ah yeah. As you can see by my comment, I re-read it as equal to. You're correct. My apologies. I've fixed my code.

Comment: No problem.  It happens to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

merge your condition like this

```
if ($name != "alex" || $name!="james"){
        echo '<script> alert("error");</script>';
        echo '<script> window.location.replace("demo.php");</script>';
}
```

if you want to `$name` not equals to both `alex` and `james` use `&&` to merge the condition like this

```
 if ($name != "alex" && $name!="james"){
            echo '<script> alert("error");</script>';
            echo '<script> window.location.replace("demo.php");</script>';
    }
```

Comment: This would always be true since name can never equal two different things.